# Is $ y = \int_0^x \frac{du}{\sqrt{x^4 - u^4}} $ an increasing or decreasing function of $x$? Find an integral expression of $y'$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Is
$$ y = \int_0^x \frac{du}{\sqrt{x^4 - u^4}} $$
an increasing or decreasing function of $x$? Find an integral expression of $y'$.

I don't understand what I need to know to solve this question. It was given as a practice revision question before commencing a course on differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the substitution $u=xz$ we get:
$$
y=\int_0^1{\frac{xdz}{\sqrt{x^4-x^4z^4}}}=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^1{\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^4}}}=\frac{c}{x}
$$
For the constant $c=\int_0^1{\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^4}}}$. Now the questions are easy to solve.